# How should I structure this C++ program?

Tags: c++, object, structure

My goal is to make a game achievement system, where you add players (which have a name, integer id, games they play), games (which have names, integer ids, list of achievements) and achievements (which have names, integer ids, and the game id that that achievement belongs to).

I am not asking for any code, I am asking how this program would ideally be structured. At a first glance, I would simply have a list of players, each player class contains games they play, each game class contains achievements. But the problem is the player itself must have the achievement, and each player's games they play must reference to the same game, not individual copies of the same game for each player.

What is the best way to structure a program such as this?

Comment: Player has achievements, achievements are linked to games.

Comment: As something I forgot to mention, I also need to be able to list the games a player plays, even if the player doesn't have achievements for the game.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to store a *handle* to a player's games in the player class rather than actual games themselves (they will be stored elsewhere).  A handle can be a pointer (which would be a *smart* pointer), an index into an array or `vector` or such-like, or some other layer of abstraction that refers to the game.

Answer (score 1):

I know that there will be several designs for class. This can be one of them. I just use `std::list` and want to show a base and simple design, not practical. So, you have to concern this before applying to your situation.

```
using namespace std;

class Achievement
{
  public:

  Achievement(string name, int id) : name_(name), id_(id) {}

  string    name_;
  int       id_;
};

typedef list<Achievement> ACHIEVEMENT_LIST;
class Game
{
  public:
  Game(string name, int id) : name_(name), id_(id) {}

  string    name_;
  int       id_;
  ACHIEVEMENT_LIST achievement_list_;
};

typedef list<Game>  PLAYED_GAME_LIST;
class Player
{
  public:

  Player(string name, int id) : name_(name), id_(id) {}

  string    name_;
  int       id_;
  PLAYED_GAME_LIST  played_game_list;
};


int main()
{

  //firstly, player A, B joins 'dungeon' Game
  Player a("A", 01);
  Player b("B", 02);

  Game dungeon("dungeon", 1001);

  //when game finishes, create achievement
  Achievement hero("hero", 100001);

  //and, add to achievement_list in Game
  dungeon.achievement_list_.push_back(hero);


  //add 'dungeon' to played_game_list.
  a.played_game_list.push_back(dungeon);
  b.played_game_list.push_back(dungeon);

  //Player a,b have same game reference 
  Game a_played_game = a.played_game_list.front();
  Game b_played_game = b.played_game_list.front();

  cout << "GAME : a_played_game.name_ = " << a_played_game.name_ << ", b_played_game.name_ = " << b_played_game.name_ << endl;

  //we can access achievement in player class
  Achievement a_achive = a_played_game.achievement_list_.front();
  Achievement b_achive = b_played_game.achievement_list_.front();

  cout << "ACHIEVEMENT : a_achive.name_ = " << a_achive.name_ << ", b_achive.name_ = " << b_achive.name_ << endl;


  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```